# Haskell 'showInt' not in scope: why not?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to understand Philip Wadler's "Essence of Functional Programming", and I seem to be held back by his assertion that "No knowledge of Haskell is necessary to understand this paper."  Maybe not, but his examples sure require some.

Specifically, I'm trying to understand [his example interpreter](https://gist.github.com/mitchellh/1079807).  When I try to compile this using GHC, or load it using `:load`, it complains `not in scope: showint.  Perhaps you meant showInt`.  When I replace the token with `showInt`, it says `Not in scope: showInt`.

I'd really like to believe Dr. Wadler when he says all I need to know is contained in his paper.

I'd really like to get it working under GHCI, so I can try various expressions under the interpreter.  I'm new to Haskell, and was duly warned about the opaqueness of its error messages, but this seems designed to perplex!

Comment: There is a [`showInt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Numeric.html#v:showInt) in base, but it returns a `ShowS` type, which is as alias for `String -> String`, so it wouldn't typecheck here either.  This looks more like a mistake in his code than anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `showInt` function is part of the `Numeric` module, so you have to `import Numeric` to have it in scope. I guess the typo hint system knows about modules you haven't imported.

`showInt` also doesn't return a string directly but instead a `String -> String` function. I think this functionality is used for showing things composed of multiple parts more efficiently, but here it'd just be a pain and your code won't typecheck as is.

Instead, you can replace `showint` with just `show` and let the compiler figure it out. `show` is Haskell's `toString` and is overloaded for any type it's reasonable to convert to a string.

Comment: Apparently, 2014's GHCi is a little bit different from the version when this paper came out in 1992.

Comment: 22 years does things to a language.

Comment: @ElfSternberg: That paper is almost a year older than I am :/.